# How to search freebase for given names

Tags: freebase, mql

Context: I am geek but brand new to the Freebase APIs.

I found this page describing [Given Name type](http://www.freebase.com/base/givennames/given_name?instances=) on Freebase and have tried to query it and am meeting with frustration.  I have tried:

```
[{
   "domain": "/base/givennames",
   "given_name": null
}]
```

which gives a "Type /type/object does not have property domain" error and

```
[{
   "type": "/givennames",
   "given_name": null
}]
```

which gives an "Unable to load schema for /givennames" error.

I am guessing that I am missing something important on the page describing the type. Any assistance is appreciated.

Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Build Query" menu option on the far right hand side of the schema page is a good way to get started with queries.  In this case you want something like [this](https://www.freebase.com/query?autorun=1&q=%5B%7B%22id%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull,%22type%22%3a%22/base/givennames/given_name%22%7D%5D):

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/base/givennames/given_name"
}]
```